# Keep getting "None" at every input statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just making a Rock , Paper and scissor game in python(Version 3.9+)  but whenever I try to run , there is NONE written at every input statement...
My whole program works fine but  I am really annoyed with "NONE" is there anything I am doing something wrong in my code.
I will really appreciate your help!

Here is my code:

```
    import random

num__round = int(input("Enter the number of rounds you want to play for: "))
rounds = 1 
while rounds <= num__round:

    comp_choices = ["Rock" , "Paper" , "Scissor"]
    
    print("Round number", rounds)
    
    user_action = str(input(print("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor"))).lower()
    comp_actions = str(random.choice(comp_choices)).lower()

    
    if user_action == comp_actions:
        
        print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "Computer Chose ==>" , comp_actions , "\nRound draw\n")
    
    elif user_action == 'rock':
        
        if comp_actions == 'paper':
            
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions)
            print("Paper defeats rock!\n<===You lost this round===>,Computer won this round!\n")
        
        else:
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions)
            print("Rock breaks scissor!\n<===You won this round!===>\n")
    
    
    elif user_action == 'paper':
        
        if comp_actions == 'rock':
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions , "\n")
            print("Paper defeats rock!\n<===You won this round===>,Computer lost!" , "\n")
        
        else:
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions)
            print("Scissor torn the paper into pieces!\n<===You lost this round===>,Computer won!\n")
    
    else:
        
        if comp_actions == 'rock':
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions ) 
            print("Rock brutally breaks the scissor!\n<===You lost this round===>,Computer won\n")
        
        else:
            print("You Chose==>" , user_action , "\nComputer Chose ==>" , comp_actions) 
            print("Scissor torn down the paper!\n<===You won this round===>,Computer lost this 
            round!\n")
    
    rounds  = rounds + 1
```

And here is the "None"  written in every input statement:

```
 Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor None rock
```

Comment: You shouldn't put the `print` inside the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `print()` from your input:

```
str(input("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor\n")).lower()
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` is willing to prompt your

```
"Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor"
```

on its own but you also put a `print` there. So first `print` prints what you give it, and then its return value (print returns `None`) is passed to `input` and `input` then prompts this `None` (if you notice, it's on a newline actually because your print gave a newline).

So you dont need `print` there:

```
user_action = str(input("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor")).lower()
```

More, you don't need to cast `str` the input's result because it's always a string (if succeeds), so

```
user_action = input("Enter your choice from ===> Rock, Paper or Scissors: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied this myself and got the NONE to go away by moving the input().lower() out of the print statement

```
print("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor")
    
user_action = str(input()).lower()
comp_actions = str(random.choice(comp_choices)).lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

whenever you see none its because your using print twice

change this:

```
user_action = str(input(print("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor"))).lower()
```

to this:

```
user_action = str(input("Enter your choice from ===> Rock , Paper or Scissor")).lower()
```

you are saying to print the function and then print the string that will take and input, which is in your function so your saying print twice, when you only need to say print the function and since the string that will take and input is in your function it will print it out.